# Why is this function in an infinite loop - learning lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, infinite-loop

(EDIT: I'm not going to worry about TCO yet)

I'm (finally getting around to) learning Lisp. I'm trying to write my own (naive-ish) function to flatten a list. I'm starting with the simpler cases and will build it up to handle more complex cases if it doesn't work. Unfortunately right now, I'm getting an infinite loop and can't quite figure out why.

I also don't know how to use any debugging methods in lisp so if you could point me in that direction, too I'd appreciate it.

```
(defun flattenizer (lst)
  (if (listp (car lst))
    (flattenizer (car lst))
    (if (null lst)
      nil
      (cons (car lst) (flattenizer (cdr lst))))))
```

final code:

```
(defun flattenizer (lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst) nil)
    ( (consp (car lst)) 
        (nconc (flattenizer (car lst)) (flattenizer (cdr lst)) ))
    (T (cons (car lst) (flattenizer (cdr lst))))))
```

tests:

```
* (flattenizer '((1 2) (3 4)))

(1 2 3 4)
* (flattenizer '(1 (2 3) (4 5)))

(1 2 3 4 5)
* (flattenizer '((1 2) 3 (4 5) 6))

(1 2 3 4 5 6)
* (flattenizer '(1 2 3 4))

(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: I would call the variable `LST` just `LIST`. I would also use `FIRST` and `REST` instead of `CAR` and `CDR`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(listp NIL)` returns `T`, and so does `(listp (car NIL))`, so when you hit the end-of-list and recurse on `NIL`, looping happens.

You need to change the order of your tests, testing for the `(null lst)` first, to avoid the looping. Better re-write it with `cond` for that. It's easier to change the ordering of tests, with `cond`.

Then you'll notice that for some reason you only flatten the first element in your argument list, ever. What about `(3 4)` in `((1 2) (3 4))` etc.? We should really somehow combine the results of flattening the `car` with the results of flattening the `cdr`.

If the result of flattening a list is a list, then we will need to combine the two resulting lists. Also, since we will be combining lists, if we encounter an atom we will have to produce a list, as the result of flattening that atom.

Comment: Awesome. +1 for giving me the hint without giving me the answer. I had a feeling I'd have to treat a nested list like a tree and recurse down each branch.

Comment: that's what (once was) called "car-cdr" recursion - the most basic and the most inefficient. :)

Answer (score 5):

`NIL` is somewhat "strange" in Common Lisp for a mix of practical and historical reasons. For example:

- `NIL` is a symbol: `(symbolp NIL) ==> T`
- `NIL` is a list: `(listp NIL) ==> T`
- `NIL` is **not** a cons cell: `(consp NIL) ==> NIL`
- but you can take `car`/`cdr` of it anyway: `(car NIL) ==> NIL` and `(cdr NIL) ==> NIL`

In your code calling recursively for `(car x)` when `(listp (car x))` is causing infinite recursion because `NIL` is a list and its `car` is itself.

Comment: thanks for the explicit reason i was in an infinite loop. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**Debugging using SBCL.**

Tell SBCL you want debug:

```
* (proclaim '(optimize (debug 3)))
```

Your code:

```
* (defun flattenizer (lst)
    (if (listp (car lst))
      (flattenizer (car lst))
      (if (null lst)
        nil
        (cons (car lst) (flattenizer (cdr lst))))))

FLATTENIZER
```

Stepping it with `STEP`

```
* (step (flattenizer '(1 (2 3) 4)))
; Evaluating call:
;   (FLATTENIZER '(1 (2 3) 4))
; With arguments:
;   (1 (2 3) 4)
```

next step

```
1] step
; Evaluating call:
;   (FLATTENIZER (CDR LST))
; With arguments:
;   ((2 3) 4)
```

next step

```
1] step
; Evaluating call:
;   (FLATTENIZER (CAR LST))
; With arguments:
;   (2 3)
```

next step

```
1] step
; Evaluating call:
;   (FLATTENIZER (CDR LST))
; With arguments:
;   (3)
```

next step

```
1] step
; Evaluating call:
;   (FLATTENIZER (CDR LST))
; With arguments:
;   NIL
```

next step

```
1] step
; Evaluating call:
;   (FLATTENIZER (CAR LST))
; With arguments:
;   NIL
```

next step

```
1] step
; Evaluating call:
;   (FLATTENIZER (CAR LST))
; With arguments:
;   NIL
```

Looks like you are in a loop now.

Getting back to the toplevel.

```
1] top

*
```

Now check your source code.